# Display nested-data in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to display collection of Person objects in a DataGrid, so that information about Person, Address, Dependents and Awards can also be viewed.

```
public class Person
{
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public IList<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
        public IList<Award> Awards { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Dependent
{
        public string DependentName { get; set; }
        public int DependentAge { get; set; }
}

public class Award
{
        public string AwardName { get; set; }
        public DateTime AwardDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried/trying HierarchicalDataTemplate, no success yet.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- template for Address, Dependent or Awards types -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The second option is to use [row details](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#rowDetails).

The third option is to use some control for displaying selected row details:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <!-- The rest of grid here -->
</DataGrid>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myGrid}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- The template for person's details -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```